# check service is running or not

Tags: android

I Have a service that when i start it, schedule with alarm manager to run on 00:00,
i want check that my service is running or not ?

when i check in Settings -> Applications -> Running Tasks, My Service Exist In Cached Process so below code is not working, because my service noting in running service, can any one help to me ?

```
private boolean isServiceRunning(String serviceName) {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> l = am.getRunningServices(50);
        Iterator<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> i = l.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo = (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo) i.next();
            if( runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(serviceName) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[BindService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) returns false if you don't have success in bind to the service:

> Returns
>
> If you have successfully bound to the service, true is returned; false is returned if the 
>   connection is not made so you will not receive the service object.

I would use that to check if the service is not running.

Just be sure to not bind with AUTO_CREATE flag, or the service will be created as well.

Answer (score 1):

I use following from inside an activity:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```